# How to get value from nested interface

Tags: go, reflection, odbc

I have a small problem while trying to dynamically read string from my db using [odbc](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc) and no ORM.

Maybe it's worth mentioning that with another SQL server driver I receive the data as string and not []uint8 which solving my problem).

I'm using the following code to scan a row into slice array:

```
func createEmptyResultSet(numOfCols int) []interface{} {
res := make([]interface{}, numOfCols)
for col := 0; col < numOfCols; col++ {
    var i interface{}
    res[col] = &i
}
return res
```

}
and the actual scan:

```
func rowsToStringInterfaceMapSlice(rows *sql.Rows, cols []string) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    rowsRes := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    numOfCols := len(cols)
    for rows.Next() {
        row := make(map[string]interface{}, numOfCols)
        values := createEmptyResultSet( numOfCols)
        if rows.Scan(values...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        rowsRes = append(rowsRes, row)
    }
    return rowsRes, nil
}
```

I'm trying to access the following slice:

[image]

using few versions of the following code:

```
  for i := range values {
//also tried multiple get value
                t := reflect.TypeOf(values[i])
                if t.Kind() == reflect.Slice {
                    row[cols[i]] = interfaceSliceToString(values[i])
                } else {
                    row[cols[i]] = values[i]
                }
            }
```

but nothing seems to work. 
any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values in `values` have type `*interface{}`.  The test for a slice will never succeed.

Use the following function to simplify things. This function returns a slice of values and a slice of pointers to the the values.  Use the first slice
for accessing the values and the second slice as the variadic argument to scan.

```
func createEmptyResultSet(numOfCols int) (values []interface{}, args []interface{}) {
    values = make([]interface{}, numOfCols)
    args = make([]interface{}, numOfCols)
    for col := 0; col < numOfCols; col++ {
        args[col] = &values[col]
    }
    return
}
```

Use it like this:

```
    values, args := createEmptyResultSet( numOfCols)
    if rows.Scan(args...); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
```

Now `values` contains the actual values instead of a pointer to the value.

Use type assertions instead of reflect to find the `[]byte` values.

```
for i, v := range values {
   switch v := v.(type) {
   case []byte:
      row[cols[i]] = string(v)
   default:
      row[cols[i]] = v
   }
}
```

Here's complete code for `rowsToStringInterfaceMapSlice`:

```
func rowsToStringInterfaceMapSlice(rows *sql.Rows, cols []string) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var err error
    rowsRes := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    numOfCols := len(cols)
    for rows.Next() {
        row := make(map[string]interface{}, numOfCols)
        values, args := createEmptyResultSet( numOfCols)
        if rows.Scan(args...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        for i, v := range values {
           switch v := v.(type) {
           case []byte:
              row[cols[i]] = string(v)
           default:
              row[cols[i]] = v
           }
        }
        rowsRes = append(rowsRes, row)
    }
    return rowsRes, nil
}
```

The `values` and `args` slices can be reused from row to row. 
Allocate `values` and `args` outside the loop to reduce memory pressure.

```
func rowsToStringInterfaceMapSlice(rows *sql.Rows, cols []string) ([]map[string]interface{}, error) {
    rowsRes := make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
    values, args := createEmptyResultSet(len(cols))
    for rows.Next() {
        row := make(map[string]interface{}, len(cols))
        for i := range values {
            values[i] = nil
        }
        if err := rows.Scan(args...); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        for i, v := range values {
            switch v := v.(type) {
            case []byte:
                row[cols[i]] = string(v)
            default:
                row[cols[i]] = v
            }
        }
        rowsRes = append(rowsRes, row)
    }
    return rowsRes, nil
}
```